# MySQL Query: How to do this one?

Tags: sql

I know this table isn't as it should be but it just is and it can't be changed.

My Table:

```
|carID  | car1      | car2      | car3      |
-------------------------------------------------
|   1   | someCar 1 | someCar 2 | someCar 3 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

And I want the following result like it should be in a relation table:

```
|carID  |car        |
---------------------
|1      | someCar 1 |
|1      | someCar 2 |
|1      | someCar 3 |
```

Does someone know how to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT carId, car1, car2, car3 FROM cars WHERE carId = '1' GROUP BY car1, car2, car3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION`

```
SELECT   CarID, car1 car FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT   CarID, car2 car FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT   CarID, car3 car FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT CarID, Car1 FROM myTable WHERE carID='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT CarID, Car2 FROM myTable WHERE carID='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT CarID, Car3 FROM myTable WHERE carID='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a union of three selects:

```
SELECT carID, car1 FROM cars WHERE carID = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT carID, car2 FROM cars WHERE carID = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT carID, car3 FROM cars WHERE carID = '1'
```

**Please note** that you need to use `UNION ALL`, not just `UNION`, because `UNION` alone would leave out duplicates. For example, if `car2` and `car3` were the same, the result would only contain two records.